# Bulk rename and capture existing names

Tags: php, batch-file, unicode, rename

I'm trying to find a way to rename all the files in a directory sequential numbers while correlating the number to the original file name in an output file like CSV. Then a script to reverse the process by reading the file name search the output file for the name and restore the name to the file. This is to bypass limitations in CD file names.

Background:
We have an offline system that is used to process files. It is maintained stand alone for security. The only method permitted for transferring data to be processed is CD/DVD.

New software is not permitted. Powershell is not available as it has been locked out. We use PHP to process the data. So built in batch and PHP are really the only options other than manually performing the rename.

We process over 2000 files a day and manual renaming is time consuming.

Details:
The files have unicode names in mixed languages over 120 characters.
The CD tools will not accept more than 120 characters and sometimes drops unicode text from names.
We have a manual process that involves copying the file name to spreadsheet then renaming the file with the row number from the spreadsheet. After burn and transfer the process is reversed by renaming the file with the name in the row matching its number.

Query:
Can PHP perform this operation and if so does anyone have an example of a similar script?

Answer (score 1):

This package can rename files in directory using several strategies.

See   [PHP File Renamer](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8130-PHP-Rename-files-in-directory-using-several-strategies.html) from phpclasses!

It can traverse a directory recursively and rename files according to several different types of strategies.

Each strategy defines how each file should be renamed or not.

Currently several types of strategies are implemented like transliteration of names in different idioms and prefix names with a time values. Additional strategies may be registered.

The renamed files may be copied to a separate directory.

The class can also generate a report in CSV format about the renamed files.

Comment: This looks interesting. The super minimal documentation doesn't include any examples of renaming files from an excel sheet. Can it do that? I've been back and forth through the code and do not see anything like that functionality. Maybe I missed it?